# .Copy the contents of the first string into the second string in the reverse order. (use loop)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

question: Create two strings of size 12. Load one of the strings with user input
characters (use loop). The second string should be kept blank..Copy the contents of the first string into the second string in the reverse order. (use loop)
//THIS IS MY CODE.BUT MY STRING ALSO STORE THE INPUT IN SAME ORDER NOT IN REVERSE ORDER.WHAT is the problem?
INCLUDE EMU8086.INC

.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 100H
.DATA

```
S1 DB 3 DUP(?),  '$'
S2 DB 3 DUP(?),  '$'
```

.CODE

```
MOV AX,@DATA 
MOV DS,AX

MOV AH,1
MOV SI,0
MOV CX,3


_IN: 
    INT 21H
    MOV S1[SI],AL
    INC SI

LOOP _IN  

PRINTN
MOV SI,0  
MOV DI, 2 
MOV CX, 3

_COPY:
    MOV AL,S1[SI] 
    MOV S2[DI],AL
    INC SI
    DEC DI

LOOP _COPY    

LEA BP,S2


MOV AH,9
INT 21H  




EXIT:
 MOV AH,4CH
 INT 21H
```

END

Comment: The input and copying looks ok to me, except the question said size 12 but you're using only 3.  Not a [mcve] because you didn't describe what you actually get when running it, and what you see with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Peter Cordes already told you in a comment, the input and copying are fine.

However displaying the result has an error:

> ```
> LEA BP,S2
> MOV AH,9
> INT 21H
> ```

This DOS function expects the pointer in the `DX` register, and you've accidentally used `BP` that will contain garbage in this case!

```
LEA DX, S2
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
```